# Parallel read/write on socket

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Does it make sense to both write and read on a socket (`SOCK_STREAM`) in parallel with multiple threads? On Linux. Do those syscalls block each other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it makes sense. Since they are in separate threads they do not block each other.

Comment: It's not that easy to say whether they "block" each other or not - that depends on the _implementation_ behind the socket, or even on the hardware (think: full/half duplex network interfaces). Agreed, from the system call interface side of things, they don't.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense as long as there is exactly one writer and one reader thread. If you have more than one reader thread you need to lock reading if you have more than one writer thread you have to lock writing.

Comment: In a multi-reader or multi-writer situation, in addition to locking, you'll also need clearly defined message boundaries for the other end of the socket to make sense of it all.  And be aware that send() and recv() are not guaranteed to transfer the amount of data you tell them to.